# Forms.WebBroswer capture user input

Tags: c#, winforms

I have used a Forms.WebBrowser to enable my users to enter their username and password.

After the point where they press login on the web page, is it possible to capture the username please?

Or is there another way to do it somehow?

the process is:

My form, with the webbrowser on it, and a prepopulated url, opens the remote webpage.

On that webpage are a username and password input boxes.

I want to be able to capture whatever the user types into the username box when they click "Login"

Comment: So you like to link to google login page, and then when the user has entered their password you want to save it? :)  I doubt that it's possible.

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive? Maybe put some code up? The user is entering the username in a textbox, then hitting a submit button, so presumably, you should be able to capture it at that point. But maybe I don't understand the question EDIT - so its not your web page that they're logging in on? I that's right, each service has their own api for accessing user information, usually including username.

Comment: @EthanPelton ive added a little more information above. correct, it's not my webpage.

Comment: You can use HtmlElement.AttachEvent() to subscribe an event handler to any of the DOM events.  The login button's onclick could work for example.  Or onblur for the textbox, less likely you'll do battle with the javascript in the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do what you are asking, Basically to capture those values you should have the logic in the web page itself, Since its not your site you cannot achieve it, But there is a workaround you can try,

Its possible to get each key user press when the focus is on the Browser control, So whatever user types within the loaded form can be captured within the windows form(*But there is no way to identify whether its typed in username field or any other*)

Within Browser control's `PreviewKeyDown` event you can capture the keyboard keys pressed.

```
//define a string variable in the class level
string typedString = null;

private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    var key = Convert.ToChar(e.KeyCode);
    typedString += key;
}
```